# Language, Proof & Logic 9.17 (9) Exercise

Tags: first-order-logic

The exercise 9.17 of [Language, Proof and Logic](https://ggweb.gradegrinder.net/lpl) course goes like this:

> Start a new sentence file, and enter translations of the following sentences. This time each translation will contain exactly one $\forall$ and no $\exists$.
>
> 9. *All dodecahedra are not small* [Note: Most people find this sentence ambiguous. Can you find both readings? One starts with $\forall$, the other with $\neg$. Use the former, the one that means all the dodecahedra are either medium and large.]

I have passed the assignment successfully and my translation was:
$$
\forall x (Dodec(x) \rightarrow \neg Small(x))
$$

My question is what is the other ambiguous interpretation for that English language sentence that authors hint on (the one that starts from $\neg$).

Comment: The other interpretation is what would be more properly formulated as "Not all dodecahedra are small", I suppose. Personally, I would never interprete the given sentence this way.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, it seems likely to be what they intended! Neither would I though! The statement of yours seems to be very fitting, but when I compare it with the original English sentence (even knowing the answer, presumably), seeing one as an interpretation of another still feels counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known saying "All that glitters is not gold"

The literal translation of this would be:

$$\forall x(Glitters(x) \rightarrow \neg Gold(x))$$

but it is clear that what this saying really means is:

$$\neg \forall x(Glitters(x) \rightarrow Gold(x))$$

Maybe that's the 'ambiguity' they are referring to?  Though I must say, I think the only reasonable interpretation of "All dodecahedra are not small" is what you have, and "All that glitters is not gold"  is just a very poor way of saying "Not all that glitters is gold"